# show :target popup on page load With PURE CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this is basic question. But I can't go through it. 
I just have the code for a popup in Pure CSS and it pops up on clicking a link  tag. 
I want this popup to be loaded on page load using either jquery or Pure JS.

Note that in CSS I have made the value of ".overlay" class's visibilty to none and on clicking changes to visible. 
I have tried to trigger a click on page load and changing the visibility on page load. Unfortunately both fails. 
I have added the code snippet. Help me Friends.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup1").trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <a id="btn" class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Notification</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      App is under-construction.
      But payment on referral income has started.
      Please stay tuned.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this instead works for me: `location.href += "#popup1";`

Comment: Got the answer.. Thanks For Everyone to take time for answering this out.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want a solution that uses "PURE CSS" as per your title, or "jquery or pure JS" as per the second sentence in the body of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Javascript for sure, you can achieve this by setting the hash manually:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.location.hash = "#popup1";
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Notification</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      App is under-construction.
      But payment on referral income has started.
      Please stay tuned.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: window.location.hash means ?

Comment: It doesn't work .. I need the popup to come on pageload

Comment: Hey... Sorry It Works.. I have added the script at the bottom of my page and it works..

Comment: @HarishST `window.location.hash` is the part after the URL with the `#` symbol. The CSS `:target` selector is active whenever the hash in the URL matches the `id` of that particular element.

Comment: Thank you so much for this fast and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var href = $('#btn').attr('href');
 window.location.href = href;
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <a id="btn" class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Notification</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      App is under-construction.
      But payment on referral income has started.
      Please stay tuned.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```